# XSLT number formatting with rounding displays negative zero

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

Is there any way to prevent XSLT showing a negative zero value when formatting small negative numbers that require rounding?

The following code

```
<xsl:variable name="myNum" select="-0.0001"/>
MyNum = <xsl:value-of select="$myNum"/>
MyNumrounded = <xsl:value-of select="format-number($myNum, '0.0%')"/>
```

Will generate the following result

```
MyNum = -0.0001
MyNumrounded = -0.0%
```

Ideally it would show

```
MyNum = -0.0001
MyNumrounded = 0.0%
```

I'm currently using Saxon HE 9.5.0.1

The complete test XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <test>
            <xsl:variable name="myNum" select="-0.0001"/>
            MyNum = <xsl:value-of select="$myNum"/>
            MyNumrounded = <xsl:value-of select="format-number($myNum, '0.0%')"/>
        </test>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Regards,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually **round** the number - not just format it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(round($myNum), '0.0%')"/>
```

Or, since you want to round to a tenth of a percent:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(round($myNum * 1000) div 1000, '0.0%')"/>
```

Note however that the specification for the [round() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-round) states that:

> If the argument is less than zero, but greater than or equal to -0.5,
>   then negative zero is returned.

But I believe this is implemented only in Saxon 6.5.

Comment: No, all Saxon releases will round the xs:double value -0.3 to negative zero. What has changed is that in XPath 2.0, the literal -0.3 denotes a decimal value, not a double value, and there is no negative zero in the xs:decimal value space.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but rounding is not really an ideal solution. I would then need to know how many decimal places I'm using ... the format pattern is being given as a parameter and can always be different. We have played with the idea of passing the number of places together with the format, but this seems rather overkill.

Comment: @MichaelKay "*there is no negative zero in the xs:decimal value space.*" Still, `format-number(xs:decimal($myNum), '0.0%')` returns negative zero in this example.

Comment: @MarkMiller I an afraid I don't have a better answer. You could of course parametrize the precision (and perhaps it could be done more simply that what has been suggested by Tobias).

Comment: This query returns "0.0%" with Saxon 9.5: `let $myNum := <a>-0</a> return format-number(xs:decimal($myNum), '0.0%')`. What processor are you using?

Comment: @MichaelKay The one [here](http://xslttest.appspot.com/). I believe it's Saxon 9.3.0.5. But the test was done with -0.0001 as the value of $myNum. I get the same result as you do when $myNum = -0.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing information. The spec for format-number() says that a "-" sign should be included in the output if the input is negative, and Saxon does what the spec says. It turns out this has nothing to do with negative zero.

Comment: @MichaelKay "*The spec for format-number() says that a "-" sign should be included in the output if the input is negative*" That makes perfect sense, even to me*. So it seems there's no choice but to round the number first. -- (*) I say "even to me" because I'm having a hard time with the concept of signed zero; it goes against my 4th-grade math.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it is the simplest solution but it still requires that the precision is parameterized. I would have preferred to have solved this without requiring the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`format-number` does not actually round a number, it just formats it.
To round a number you can either use `round()`,`ceiling()` or `floor()` depending on what you want to do.

So doing:

```
<xsl:variable name="myNum" select="-0.0001"/>
MyNum = <xsl:value-of select="$myNum"/>
MyNumrounded = <xsl:value-of select="format-number(round($myNum), '0.0%')"/>
```

would result in:

```
MyNum = -0.0001
MyNumrounded = 0.0%
```

However be aware that round always rounds to a full integer, so 0.1 would result in 0.0% as well.
To round to a certain digit you'd have to write your own function.
So just in case, since you're using Saxon 9.5 you can use XSLT 2.0 so here's a set of functions you can use to round to a decimal place:

```
<xsl:function name="f:pow">
    <xsl:param name="base" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="exp" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$exp eq 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$base"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$base * f:pow($base, $exp - 1)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="f:roundToDecimal">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:param name="dec" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mult" select="f:pow(10,$dec)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$input castable as xs:double">
        <xsl:value-of select="round($input * $mult) div $mult"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

So basically multiply your number with a power of 10, round, divide by the same power of 10.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using XPath 1.0 mode in your stylesheet, so that -0.0001 is being treated as an xs:double rather than an xs:decimal. The simplest solution might be to switch to XPath 2.0 mode (set version="2.0") so this will be done in decimal arithmetic. The xs:decimal data type has no negative zero.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I'm actually using XPath 2.0 though ... at least I think I am.